Есть ли замена Firebase в России?
Есть ли mbaas сервера для мобильного приложения в России с noSql как firebase?

Не знаю насчёт NoSQL, но есть такие альтернативы supabase, Gotify их можно селф хостить. А так же сервис от Huawei - HMS Core он так вообще косит под Firebase, во всяком случае легко было переписать Firebase Cloud Messaging на Huawei Push Kit.

попробуй посмотреть на сайтах этих 3 компаний:

Selectel
Яндекс
Cloud.ru

